# how to set session in front(nuxtjs)?

Tags: vue.js, express, session, nuxt.js

I have code to set the session that works in postman

**First**: set my session and it work

```js
const user = {
  name: 'afshin',
};
req.session.user = user
res.status(200).send({data:req.session.user,status:200});
```

**Second**: retrieve session

```js
console.log(req.session.user)
```

This works when I make a request with postman. But when I use on client (nuxt + axios) it isn't working

**Third**: on the front-end

```js
this.$axios
  .post(
    'http://localhost:7000/auth/session-result',
    { data: 'salam' },
    {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    },
    { withCredentials: true },
  )
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
    this.setState({
      errorMessage: `Server Error`,
      loading: false,
    })
  })
```

What am I doing wrong the front-end?

Comment: Share the postman request body that is working.

Comment: `req` is for server side, so you will not get it on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`req` is for server side, so you will not get it on the client side, as shown on [this page](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/context-helpers), this is only for server side.

[image]